# Making an Eigen::Vector look like a vector of points

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to represent a 2D shape in such a way that it can be interacted with as if it were a vector of points, in particular I want to be able to call operator`[]` and `at()` on it and return references to things that act like 2D points. Currently I just use a class whose only member variable is a vector of points and that has various arithmetic and geometric operations defined pointwise on its elements.

However, in other parts of my code I need to treat a vector of n points as an element of 2n dimensional space and perform basic linear algebra on it (e.g. projecting the vector onto a given subspace of R^2n). Currently I'm creating an `Eigen::VectorXd` object every time I want to do this, and then converting back after performing these operations. I don't want to do this, as I make the conversion often enough that all the copying is a noticeable source of inefficiency.

If I was storing the data as a flat array of doubles/floats/ints, I could cast a pointer to its nth element to a pointer to a Point (whose members would just be a pair of doubles/floats/ints). However, as I don't know the internal representation that Eigen uses for vectors (and it may well change), this isn't possible.

Is there a sensible way of solving this? I could just use `Eigen::Vector`s everywhere, but I really want most of the code to be able to pretend that it is dealing with a set of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, as I don't know the internal representation that Eigen uses for vectors (and it may well change), this isn't possible.

Eigen offers the `Map` classes that allow mapping plain arrays to Eigen structures. For example:

```
double numbers[2];
Eigen::Vector2f::Map( numbers ).dot( Eigen::Vector2f::Constant(1) );
```

Comment: Thanks. In the other direction, is the data of a dense matrix guaranteed to be contiguous? i.e. is it safe to assume that mat<T,a,b>.data() returns a pointer to an array of Ts?

Comment: @user967771: I think so (by the definition of "dense matrix"), but don't have proof. The `data` member of `PlainObjectBase` wouldn't much make sense without continuous storage.

Comment: It appears that it is. Thanks.